# Remove noise from audio sample record using audiorecorder

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I am making TalkingTomcat like app. I am recording voice using android audio recorder and using libsonic I am playing sound by changing pitch. but during playing sound it give a lot of noise.
Even i am playing sound sample using audio track then also it give noice.
I am using 44100 sample rate and MONO and 16 bits.

If anyone can help me please help me. Or give me another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do noise removal at the pre-processing stage. Here I have filtered the audible range for speech & music. I found this to be very effective during my tests as opposed to NoiseSuppressor. Usage and utility methods,

```
recorder.read(data, 0, data.length);
if(isAudible(data)) {
    // TODO further processing can go here
}

public static boolean isAudible(short[] data) {
    double rms = getRootMeanSquared(data);
    return (rms > 198 && 5600 > rms);
}

public static double getRootMeanSquared(short[] data) {
    double ms = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        ms += data[i] * data[i];
    }
    ms /= data.length;
    return Math.sqrt(ms);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this thing, which i think about long ago. Cool!!

Comment: With that range we're still experiencing some static, is there anything else we can do to clean it up?

Comment: I don't quite understand what is being done in your code. Your rms (root mean square) is a measure of amplitude, or volume. So you are actually cutting the low and high volume sounds, and not really the noise...?

Comment: In particular, it seems you are treating a loud (music) sound as inaudible?

Answer (score 0):

have you played with [NoiseSuppressor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/NoiseSuppressor.html)? "Noise suppression (NS) is an audio pre-processing which removes background noise from the captured signal"

Comment: Noise Suppressor is in API 16 not not supporting in api below 16 and I am working in api 8.

Comment: Increase encoding bitrate

Comment: Is there any sample code for remove noise from existing audio.